# How can I setup Continuum to build on svn commits?

Tags: svn, maven-2, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, continuum

I had never tried **Continuum** as a build server until recently when a project required it.  I appreciate the integration with Maven builds however I have been unable to find a way to have Continuum build my projects on every **Subversion commit** (like **CruiseControl**).

There are several issue/bugs reported related to this topic of **triggering builds** from the configured SCM ... but all seem to be closed citing duplicate issues.  ***Has anyone gotten this to work or have any advice on how to implement it?***

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I use the post-commit hooks in svn to invoke a command or post to an url. This is pretty much how everything integrates with svn.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate Keith answer: you have to notify continuum using the [XML-RPC](http://continuum.apache.org/docs/1.2.3/developer_guides/xmlrpc.html) interface.